# Weekly forecasts with holidays

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I use Hyndman's `forecast` package to produce a somewhat accurate `tbats` forecast at the weekly level, but I have significant errors on holidays. How can I include holidays in the model? Also, Arima has been shown to fit my weekly data poorly. So holidays would have to be added in a non-arima way.

I have seen two solutions. One https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/ shows how to add holidays as dummy variables with fourier terms. The problem is dummy variables take the form of 1 or 0. I know that different holidays have different effects that a 1 or 0 would not capture. Black Friday, for example, is very different from Chinese New Year.

Another solution is have seen is here https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast7-part-2/ where covariate `nnetr` change is used as an alternative to auto.arima with seasonal dummy variables. The problem is I don't see how to write the R code to input my holidays. An example would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following did everything I needed it to do.

```
k=23
#forecast holidays
#bool list of future holidays
holidayf <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
h <- length(holidayf)

#given holidays
holiday <- df[,2] 
y <- ts(df[,1],start = 2011,frequency = 52)
z <- fourier(y, K=k)
zf <- fourier(y, K=k, h=h)
fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg=cbind(z,holiday), seasonal=FALSE)
fc <- forecast(fit, xreg=cbind(zf,holidayf), h=h)
fc %>% autoplot()
summary(fit)
```

To solve the problem of different holidays having different effect, I simply added additional holiday dummy variables. For example, you can make a vector of good holidays and a vector of bad holidays and `cbind` them then put them in `xreg`. I did not show this in the above code, but it is straight forward.

Comment: Can you please share the code for including the good and bad holidays. Thanks !!

Comment: There are no good/bad holidays. The 1 is present if there was a holiday on that day. The 0 is present of there was not a holiday on that day.

Comment: Different holidays will have a different impact on the forecast. Like black Friday will increase the sale greater than other holidays like Chinese new year. Should we take that into consideration or the model can incorporate that from the train data? Also, How did you choose the value of K?

Comment: The value of K has to be tuned. The model will estimate the effect of the holiday.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Can you please share some code for determining k value or point to some source?

Comment: This is a basic backtest. Try different values of k then see which value gave you the lowest error.

Comment: Basically minimizing the AIC? Should it be done on the holiday matrix data of 0/1 or the actual data? I found this article which shows something similar, do you think it's a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 7):

*The* benchmark for time series modeling for use by *official statistics agencies* is [x13-arima-seats](https://www.census.gov/srd/www/x13as/) by the US Census bureau.  It deals with seasonal effects as well as with "parametric" holidays including, say, the Chinese New Year as well as Easter.

The functionality is available in R via the [seasonal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seasonal/index.html) package which installs and uses the underlying x13-arima-seats binary.

And there is also a full-feature [interactive website](http://www.seasonal.website/) giving access to most-if-not-all features.

Comment: this is interesting information. Are there code examples of how it has been used in R?

Comment: Yes, there is an extended vignette by Christoph and myself as well as a draft paper, plus of course examples in the package. And Christoph has way more on in other places.  This is probably what you want.  It's still tricky, but this is AFAIK the most complete (and complex) tool.

Comment: Does it do weekly data? I thought it didn't.

Comment: Weekly is difficult with arima in general as 365 (or 366) does not evenly divide by 7 -- but not impossible.  I had at times fudged the year-end data around Xmas to fit 52 * 7 \approx 1 year.

Answer (score 6):

Have you read about Facebook's `prophet` package?

Haven't used it but from reading the documentation, it seems like a quick implementation that also accounts for holidays:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/prophet.pdf

> Implements a procedure for forecasting time series data based on
>   an additive model where non-linear trends are fit with yearly and weekly
>   seasonality, plus holidays [...]

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/vignettes/quick_start.html

Comment: I haven't used this either but I have been to a talk where someone had moved from using the forecast package to prophet and it was much easier to program holidays with as it was built in a more friendly way.

Comment: Have used it. Comes very handy when something has to be put together quick and also to integrate with shiny.